# Integrating qr-scanner plugin of cordova with Angular

Tags: android, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, qr-code

I am recently working in an Angular project. I need to convert the project into native app. I am currently using Instascan for scanning qr in my project but after converting the project to android app using cordova, the qr scanner part doesn't work. The camera doesn't show up. 
I am even unable to integrate the qr-scannerplugin of cordova. Please help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you using [cordova-plugin-qrscanner](https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner)?

Comment: @BShaps Yes, but the camera doesn't open.